# readfile function for PDF download issues

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked, but the solutions offered are not working for me. I am able to download PDFs, but Adobe Reader is telling me it's either corrupt or decoded improperly. Does anyone have an alternative solution, or possible fix?

```
$path = "http://www.laerdalmail.com/discoversimulation/downloads/needs_assessment_form.pdf";
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=needs_assessment_form.pdf"); 
readfile($path); 
exit;
```

Comment: Do you have try with base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding?

Answer (score 0):

readfile should be given a filesystem path, not a URL. something like this:

```
$path = '/websitefolder/discoversimulation/downloads/needs_assessment_form.pdff';
// or
$parh = 'c:\something\needs_assessment_form.pdff';
```

Try adding in content length too:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
```